# Use "retrieved on (German: Besucht am)" only in the bibliography if URL

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, german

I want "Besucht am:" to only appear in the bibliography if an URL is used. Unfortunately, the "Besucht am: + date" appears in all sources and there are hundreds...

Here's my code:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=authoryear-icomp, bibstyle=authoryear, sorting=nyt, 
hyperref=true, uniquename=false,]{biblatex}
```

Here are two examples from my library - only the first one should have "Besucht am: date":

```
@misc{Stiewe.2015,
 author = {M{\"u}ller, Eckhard and Stiewe, Christian},
 year = {2015},
 title = {Anwendungspotential thermoelektrischer Generatoren in station{\"a}ren Systemen Chancen f{\"u}r NRW: Studie im Auftrag des Ministeriums f{\"u}r Innovation, Wissenschaft, Forschung des Landes Nordrhein-Westfalen},
 url = {https://elib.dlr.de/100251/},
 keywords = {Anwendungspotential NRW;TEG},
 urldate = {2021-02-22}, %JJJJ-MM-TT
 editor = {{Deutsches Zentrum für Luft- und Raumfahrt e.V.}},
 institution = {{Institute of Materials Research - Thermoelectric Materials and Systems}},
 file = {673c3516-1a8e-4110-b4d2-7dccfe87d67a:C\:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Swiss Academic Software\\Citavi 6\\ProjectCache\\mubvzqt50zkfv8qpidh93k7mxrtrdnpo3gt0y1\\Citavi Attachments\\673c3516-1a8e-4110-b4d2-7dccfe87d67a.pdf:pdf}
}
@article{Rosch.2021,
 abstract = {npj Flexible Electronics, doi:10.1038/s41528-020-00098-1},
 author = {R{\"o}sch, Andres Georg and Gall, Andr{\'e} and Aslan, Silas and Hecht, Matthias and Franke, Leonard and Mallick, Md. Mofasser and Penth, Lara and Bahro, Daniel and Friderich, Daniel and Lemmer, Uli},
 year = {2021},
 title = {Fully printed origami thermoelectric generators for energy-harvesting},
 urldate = {2021-02-22},
 pages = {1--8},
 volume = {5},
 number = {1},
 journal = {npj Flexible Electronics},
 doi = {10.1038/s41528-020-00098-1},
 file = {772ca64a-a60f-4800-be17-b8d2f74ebcae:C\:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Swiss Academic Software\\Citavi 6\\ProjectCache\\mubvzqt50zkfv8qpidh93k7mxrtrdnpo3gt0y1\\Citavi Attachments\\772ca64a-a60f-4800-be17-b8d2f74ebcae.pdf:pdf}
}
```

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: why do you use urldate if there is no url?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer because citavi made it by itself. And I don't have time to remove it from thousands of references.

Comment: Does your thesis actually have thousands of references? :)

Comment: Of course not, it's a common hyperbole :)

Comment: Is it really? Well, there are maybe other solutions available depending on the actual number of entries. In this specific case, a simple "search and replace" with a text editor of your choice could have been an alternative approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

URL access dates make sense for unstable URLs, but not so much for stable DOIs (and even fairly stable elib URLs). As [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) commented it would make sense to simply get rid of the `urldate` in the `.bib` file if you don't want it. If that is not possible, here is another approach using Biber sourcemaps to get rid of it

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[notfield=url, final]
      \step[fieldset=urldate, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@report{Stiewe.2015,
  author      = {Müller, Eckhard and Stiewe, Christian},
  year        = {2015},
  title       = {Anwendungspotential thermoelektrischer Generatoren
                 in stationären Systemen},
  subtitle    = {Chancen für NRW},
  titleaddon  = {Studie im Auftrag des Ministeriums
                 für Innovation, Wissenschaft, Forschung
                 des Landes Nordrhein-Westfalen},
  type        = {DLR-Forschungsbericht},
  url         = {https://elib.dlr.de/100251/},
  urldate     = {2021-02-22},
  institution = {Deutsches Zentrum für Luft- und Raumfahrt e.V.,
                 Institut für Werkstoff-Forschung},
  location    = {Köln},
}
@article{Rosch.2021,
  author  = {Rösch, Andres Georg and Gall, André and Aslan, Silas
             and Hecht, Matthias and Franke, Leonard
             and Mallick, Md. Mofasser and Penth, Lara
             and Bahro, Daniel and Friderich, Daniel and Lemmer, Uli},
  year    = {2021},
  title   = {Fully printed origami thermoelectric generators for energy-harvesting},
  urldate = {2021-02-22},
  pages   = {1--8},
  volume  = {5},
  number  = {1},
  journal = {npj Flexible Electronics},
  doi     = {10.1038/s41528-020-00098-1},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,Stiewe.2015,Rosch.2021}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Rösch, Andres Georg u.a. (2021). „Fully printed origami thermoelectric generators for energy-harvesting“. In: npj Flexible Electronics 5.1, S. 1–8. doi: 10.1038/s41528-020-00098-1.]

Note the changes to your `Stiewe.2015` entry to make it more `biblatex`-y.

---

Small explanatory comment on the sourcemap code

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[notfield=url, final]
      \step[fieldset=urldate, null]
    }
  }
}
```

1. The first `\step` checks if there is no `url` field (`notfield=url`) and stops otherwise (`final`).
2. The second `\step` is now only executed if there is no `url` field and it sets `urldate` (`fieldset=urldate`) to `null`, i.e. deletes it.

More details about the sourcemap syntax and examples can be found in [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), §4.5.3 *Dynamic Modification of Data*, pp. 196-208 (in v3.16).

Comment: @Hanna If this answer helped solve your issue, please consider [accepting it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the green checkmark to show that the question is answered. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: +1: Can you maybe put a small comment in the code that explains the syntax of `\step[notfield=url, final] \step[fieldset=urldate, null]`?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Anything in particular you are looking for? The manual has the full extensive list of all possible options here and dumping them in the answer would be excessive.

Comment: Then sorry for the noise, I will have a look at the manual.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Well, I did try to explain the mapping in some more detail in the edit. But if there is something specifically you would like to know, you can try to look it up in the manual or ask again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is helpful!