# Biblatex: do not print "visited on" for eprint

Tags: biblatex

I'm using Zotero to manage bibliography: it automatically adds a `urldate` on `arxiv` entries which gets added to the final document as via a `visited on <date>` text:

[image]

How could I get rid of that, but only on entried that have a `eprint` field? (I want to keep `visited on` for regular websites):

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@online{ABC,
  title = {My title},
  author = {Some, One},
  date = {2021-04-10},
  eprint = {0102.34567},
  eprinttype = {arxiv},
  primaryclass = {quant-ph},
  url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/0102.34567},
  urldate = {2021-04-13},
  abstract = {blabla},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv}
}

@online{WWW,
  title = {{{WEBSITE}}},
  author = {{Author WebSite}},
  url = {https://example.org/},
  urldate = {2021-09-13},
  abstract = {Some abstract.},
  langid = {english},
  organization = {{Organization}},
}

\end{filecontents}

% BibLatex > Bibtex
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=trad-alpha]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
% Remove "visited on" for
%\usepackage{xpatch}
%\xpatchbibdriver{online}{urldate}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

Eprint like~\cite{ABC} should \emph{not} contain the ``visited on'', while normal web pages should~\cite{WWW}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/612563/35864 for the same problem with `doi` instead of `eprint`. Assuming you also don't want the URL date for DOIs, the answer there will also work here as well.

Comment: @moewe Thanks, works perfectly. Feel free to add an answer if you want me to accept it. Meanwhile I put the code I just used.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to moewe comment (thanks!) I was able to derive a map that removes `urls` and `urldate` of entries with an `eprinttype`, or for entries which are not `@online` (which means I only insert urls for `@online` elements without `eprinttype`). See more examples [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612563/use-retrieved-on-german-besucht-am-only-in-the-bibliography-if-url) or in the section `Dynamic Modification of Data` of [the BibLaTex manual](https://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      % If it contains a field eprinttype...
      \step[fieldsource=eprinttype, final]
      % ... remove the urldate and url
      \step[fieldset=urldate, null]
      \step[fieldset=url, null]
    }
    \map{
      % If it is not @online, always remove urldate and url
      \pernottype{online}
      % ... remove the urldate and url
      \step[fieldset=urldate, null]
      \step[fieldset=url, null]
    }
  }
}
```